# How is the Hahn-Banach theorem is applied here?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to understand how the Banach theorem is applied to get the following highlighted conclusions.
[image]

The only way I could think of is the following: Since the dual $X^*$ is a normed space, if $x^*_1,x^*_2 \in X^*$ are distinct functional, then by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $x \in X^{**}=X$ (by reflexivity) such that $\langle x,x^*_1 \rangle \neq \langle x,x^*_2 \rangle$ which clearly is what is concluded here. Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the proof says, $(0,x_0)$ is not in the (closed) graph of $S$. So you want to apply Hahn-Banach on the space $X\times X$. It is easy to check that you can identify $(X\times X)^*$ with $X^*\times X^*$ via
$$\tag1
\langle (x_1^*,x_2^*),(x_1,x_2)\rangle=\langle x_1^*,x_1\rangle+\langle x_2^*,x_2\rangle 
$$
and $\|(x_1^*,x_2^*)\|=\|x_1^*\|+\|x_2^*\|$.

So Hahn-Banach tells you that there exists $(x_1^*,x_2^*)\in (X\times X)^*$ such that $\langle(x_1^*,x_2^*),(0,x_0)\rangle\ne0$ and $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ is $0$ on the graph of $S$, which means that
$$
\langle x_1^*,0\rangle+\langle x_2^*,x_0\rangle=0
$$
and
$$
\langle x_1^*,x\rangle+\langle x_2^*,Sx\rangle=0
$$
for all $x\in D(S)$. You can get the minus sign if replace the duality $(1)$ with
$$\tag2
\langle (x_1^*,x_2^*),(x_1,x_2)\rangle=\langle x_1^*,x_1\rangle-\langle x_2^*,x_2\rangle.
$$

Comment: What would the norm be if you use the minus sign in the duality? It wouldn't make sense to replace the sign with minus in the norm as this may lead to a negative norm right?

Comment: The norm doesn't change. The functional $-x_2^*$ is as good an honest a functional as $x_2@^*$.

Comment: *(read that $x_2^*$, my bad)*

Comment: Hmm are you saying that we are basically considering $\|(x_1^*,x_2^*)\|=\|x_1^*\|+\|-x_2^*\|$. I am not sure I see the correspondence

Comment: If you want to see it that way, yes, I guess. $\|-x_2^*\|=\|x_2^*\|$, so you won't find a difference.

Comment: Thank you Martin!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the graph of $S,$ i.e. $\Gamma_S:=\{(x,Sx)\,:\, x\in X\}\subset X\times X.$ We have $(0,x_0)\notin \Gamma_S.$ Therefore there exists a linear functional $\varphi$ on $X\times X$ such that $\varphi(x,Sx)=0$ for any $x\in X$ and $\varphi(0,x_0)\neq 0.$ We have $(X\times X)^*=X^*\times X^*.$ Hence $\varphi=(x_1^*,x_2^*),$ and
$\varphi(x,x')=x_1^*(x)+x_2^*(x').$ Thus
$$0=\varphi(x,Sx)=x_1^*(x)+x_2^*(Sx),\quad 0\neq \varphi(0,x_0)=x_1^*(0)+x_2^*(x_0)$$